# Proof Picking Weights

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Weights $2^{w1}, 2^{w2}, ..., 2^{wn}$. It is needed to fill a bag with those weights as fast as possible. A condition has been given that we can only pick those weights if they add up to a power of $2$ i.e. if we pick weights $2^{x1}, 2^{x2}, ...,2^{xk}$, then, $2^{x1}+ 2^{x2}+ ...+2^{xk} = 2^{m}$ for some $m$. So, what is the minimum steps required to fill the bag with all those coins?

I thought of starting with a smaller case , when all of the weights are $2^0 = 1$. Then, we can notice that total weights  $W = 1+1+....+1$, which is $1$ added $n$ times. So, we can just pick those weights that add up to a power of 2, where the power is the largest. This is same as writing $W$ in binary and counting those bits that are 1.

But I can't expand this idea to other types of coins? Any help on how to prove that the answer is equal to the set bits in the binary representation of the sum of those weights.

Comment: What is the capacity of the bag? Is it $2^m$?

Comment: Bag is as large as the universe. :D

Comment: If you mean we don't need to fully fill the bag, then just picking $2^{w1}$ seems to be the minimum step solution as we only need one step and $m=w_1$. Why this is not allowed?

Comment: No, all the weights must be picked.

Comment: If all must be picked, isn't there only one way of picking? What if $2^{w1}+2^{w2}+...+2^{wn}$ is not a power of $2$?

Comment: Then, number of steps will increase.

Comment: I still don't understand, do you mean there are infinite number of coins of each weight, and we want to pick $a_1$ coins of first weight, $a_2$ coins of second weight and so on. i.e $a_12^{w1}+a_22^{w2}+...+a_n2^{w_n}$ is a power of $2$ such that $a_1,a_2,...,a_n>0$ and $a_1+a_2+...+a_n$ is minimized?

Comment: I think it has been clearly stated, there are $n$ weights of form $2^{w_i}$. You need to pick up all those coins. If there was no restriction , you could pick it up all. e.g. lets say coins were 2, 2, 2, then you could pick 2 + 2 = 4 and then 2 next, so a total of two steps, whereas if coins were 2, 2, 2, 2 then you could pick 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 8, in one step. Suppose coins were, 1 + 2 + 4 + 8, then you can see no two or more coins sum to a power of 2, so we need to pick each of them individually and minimum steps is 4.

Comment: Oh now I understood. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the binary representation of $2^{w1}+ 2^{w2}+ ...+ 2^{wn}$.

If the binary number has $k$ "$1$"s in it then let those positions be $m_1,m_2,...,m_k$ (i.e. there is a $1$ at $m_i$'s digit of the binary number). Note that all $m_i$s are different numbers because there cannot be two different $1$s in the same digit of a binary number.

$$2^{w1}+ 2^{w2}+ ...+ 2^{wn}=2^{m1}+2^{m2}+...+2^{mk}$$

We want to show that each $2^{mi}$ can be expressed as a sum of some $2^{wj}$. WLOG assmue $w_1\leq w_2\leq ... \leq w_n$ and $m_1<m_2<...<m_k$.

First we look at $m_1$.

Suppose $2^{m_1}$ cannot be expressed as a sum of some terms on the left side.

Then we substract in order, $2^{w_1},2^{w_2},...$ from it until the next one is larger then the remaining number. We let the remaining number be $x$, by definition $x=2^{m1}-2^{w1}-2^{w2}-...-2^{wl}$ where $l$ is the largest number such that $2^{w1}+2^{w2}+...+2^{wl}<2^{m1}$. By this definition we have $2^{w1}+2^{w2}+...+2^{wl}+2^{w(l+1)}>2^{m1}$ and hence $x<2^{w(l+1)}$.

The equation now becomes

$$2^{w(l+1)}+ 2^{w(l+2)}+ ...+ 2^{wn}=x+2^{m2}+...+2^{mk}$$

or

$$2^{w(l+1)}+ 2^{w(l+2)}+ ...+ 2^{wn}-2^{m2}-...-2^{mk}=x$$

Since $2^{m_1}$ cannot be expressed as a sum of $2^{wj}$ we know $x \neq 0$. Now, since $x<2^{w(l+1)}$ and $x<2^{m1}<2^{m2}$, $x$ is not divisible by $min(2^{w(l+1)}, 2^{m2})$. However the left side of the equation obviously is divisible by $min(2^{w(l+1)}, 2^{m2})$ contradiction.

Hence $m_1$ must be expressable as a sum of $w_j$. Now we cancel out $2^{m1}$ and its summand on both side from the original equation and are left with

$$2^{v1}+ 2^{v2}+ ...+ 2^{vh}=2^{m2}+...+2^{mk}$$

We can apply the same analysis again on $m_2$ and so on and show all terms on the right side can be expressed as sums of terms on the left side. Furthermore since we perform each step after eliminating terms in the previous step, there won't be any duplicated summands.

Hence the process can be completed in $k$ steps.

To show $k$ is the least, if we can complete in less than $k$ steps say $r$ steps where $r<k$, then we have

$$2^{m1}+2^{m2}+...+2^{mk}=2^{u1}+2^{u2}+...+2^{ur}$$

where $u_1\leq u_2\leq ...\leq u_r$

However the $u$ terms are in the exact same form as the original $w$ terms and we can prove each $m$ term can be expressed as non-duplicated sum of $u$ terms showing $k\geq r$ contradiction.

Comment: Good proof. But is there a more shorter and elegant one(perhaps more intuitive, less maths)?

Comment: For example, if all weights were 1, then we could group ones , (1 + 1 + 1 + 1+) + (1 + 1) + 1. Now if weights are 2, 1, 2, then we can write the weights as (1 + 1), 1, (1 + 1). Splitting all weights to 1 and then arriving at an answer fast. i.e. reducing the complex case to the simpler case with weight 1 and then solving from that simpler case will be easy.